# get post data from wordpress by sql query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to get wordpress post data and get wp_attached_file from wp_postmeta table
this is my sql query

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT wp_posts.ID,wp_posts.post_title,wp_posts.post_date,wp_postmeta.meta_value 
                FROM wp_posts

                  JOIN wp_term_relationships
                        ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID

                    JOIN wp_postmeta
                        ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID

                WHERE wp_posts.post_date > '$before7' 
                AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
                AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
                AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '$cat' 
                AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' 
                ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 10");
```

it give me nothing but if I removed this line from where clause

```
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
```

it works but I need this line to get wp_attached_file

so what is wrong with mysql query

Comment: I think you're using the default wordpress database's prefix, but the right way to refere a table in a SQL request is this de variable `$wpdb->prefix`, like this : `"SELECT ".$wpdb->prefix."posts.ID,".$wpdb->prefix."posts.post_title ...."`

Comment: You are querying for `post_type = 'post'` but if I remember right, `_wp_attached_file` is only used with `post_type = 'attachment'`

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the wp_postmeta.meta_key with the value _wp_attached_file really exist and then could be there is some problem for match  try trim  both  cause hidden  char

```
  AND trim(wp_postmeta.meta_key)  = trim('_wp_attached_file')
```